# Samba Share (Debian Squeeze) OSX Finder does not recognize free space after upgrade to Lion

Tags: debian, osx-lion, samba

The Samba share is on a software RAID and mounted under /media/share. By default Finder reports the free disk space (in the status bar) from / but there is not much space left on this partition so I cannot write files to the Samba share. I tried to correct it with the dfree configuration option. I created the script for the dfree option and tested it on the command line (it works). 
My Mac OSX Lion however is ignoring the configuration and it not displaying the free space any more.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

My problem was caused by a bad dfree script, the following one fixed my problem:

```
#!/bin/sh
df $1 | tail -1 | awk '{print $(NF-4),$(NF-2)}'
```